# Is mod_rewrite based on user-agent detectable?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is a mod_rewrite rule detectable by the end user?
What is the best way to redirect a user based on their browser type without sending proxy or redirect responses?

I am trying to ensure a user with one browser type gets the correct landing page and a user with another browser type gets the one for theirs.  However, it needs to be not detectable.

All site users will see "www.mysite.org/index.html" but the "index.html" will be different pages based on the user-agent string but I don't want any indicators like redirection status (3xx) only OK 200.

Would adding [PT] do this or adding [R] and send 200?  I don't want to send 200 as a rule in case there was an issue but I don't want users to see any indications of the local redirection.  I thought the server-side setting were hidden but someone indicated that it was detectable by the response codes.

```
Examples I found;

    # MS Internet Explorer - Mozilla v4
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/4(.*)MSIE
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.IE.html [L]

    # Netscape v6.+ - Mozilla v5
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/5(.*)Gecko
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.NS5.html [L]

    # Lynx or Mozilla v1/2
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Lynx/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[12]
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.20.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general flow of the way this works:

1. Browser sends a request to a server
2. Server receives request (at this point, the browser is waiting for a response)
3. Request goes through a number of modules, mod_rewrite being one of them
4. A mod_rewrite rule gets triggered and the URI is **re-written** to another URI
5. that URI ends up getting served and its contents are returned to the browser.

As far as the browser is concerned, this is all it sees:

1. I have a URL
2. I send a request,
3. I get content for that URL that I sent

In the first workflow, steps 2, 3, and 4 all happens solely on the server's end and so the browser doesn't know anything about it.

So you don't need a `PT` or `R` (which tells the browser to go somewhere else, thus exposing it to where the content really is).